# Pants and Shirt Not Moving Properly(Weight Paint Issue?)

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I'm having a problem adjusting the weight painting for the pants and shirt of my character. The problem is that when my character raises his foot, I don't want the top of the pants to poke through the bottom of the shirt. I already tried finding the right bones to change the weight paint influence and this helps a little, but the intersection still happens. I rigged the pants and shirt with automatic weights. Is that the best option or is there a better/easier way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Here's a video.

https://mega.nz/#!D5NA2YaR!2pSZiTbSj5V3QMSv4DA2bLbIiJRM_gQeDh6lzYFlcRY

Comment: .blend would help - even though, like you said, it really seems to be purely a weight painting issue

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. I found out that both the hip bones and the other leg bone were influencing the movement of the shirt on the leg I'm working on when they shouldn't have been. I'll need to click in between these few bones and adjust the weight painting until the shirt looks good when the leg is lifted.